# How to get Google page rank and number of searches in Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, pagerank

I have a link in one column and, based on it, I want

1. Number of Google searches in column 2
2. Page rank of first result in column 3

I know this can be done, as I saw a friend pulling google search result right in Excel. If anyone knows, please share how I could do that.

Comment: Perhaps you could start by asking your friend?

Comment: you know Bill, "friendship" is overrated nowadays... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly interpret your question, one of the tasks you had to do is

**How do I get programmatically the Google page rank for a list of URLs?**

You can find the code to do this in this CodeProject article:
[Request Google´s Pagerank programmatically](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Google_Pagerank.aspx)

Regarding the Excel part: it depends which programming framework or platforms you could use. You could use to create a .NET extension for Excel using the Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Office.

Answer (score 1):

From Excel there is Data->Get External Data->New Web Query. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, both of which are unfortunately poorly documented.

If you are comfortable in C/C++, you can write a special DLL called an "XLL" that you can call during Excel runtime. There is some sparse [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687894.aspx) available. Note that this stuff isn't very fun to use.

If you prefer .NET, there is a binding for the entire Office suite outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905533.aspx) that allows you to write COM-based methods that you can call from Office. It is intended for automation, but you can write any managed code you want and have Excel call into it.

There is also what Remou just suggested; I don't actually own a copy of Excel to test that out, but it may be the easiest option.

Answer (score 0):

By link i meant keywords and not URL. I want to put a keyword in one cell and pull number of searches and page rank in adjacent cells.

I tried doing the same with web query in excel but i can only reach till the number of searches. that too not in the proper cell (trying to figure out). But i have no clue about how to get the pageranks.

I am not that tech savvy to code a binder or plugin for myself. Although i am checking the link by splattne. Please focus more light on it. Is it gonna be time consuming if i try to make this one..?

Regards
Thinkjayant

Comment: If it is going to be so difficult, the Bill the Lizard's comment (op) is by far the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

There are some nice plugins for this (in various languages) on GitHub:

http://github.com/search?langOverride=&language=&q=pagerank&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories&x=0&y=0

Answer (score 0):

I have a PR checker functions in my Excel plugin "SeoTools".

http://nielsbosma.se/projects/seotools/